# How to get access to logcat in IntelliJ IDEA in non-Android project?

Tags: intellij-idea, logcat

I don't see it at the bottom where it usually sits. I also tried "Log Viewer" plugin which should display logcat from any project, but that plugin fails to detect my emulated device.

I mean IntelliJ IDEA, **not** Android Studio.

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure it would be available.  Perhaps there is a plugin for Android you can use.

Comment: I have installed the official "Android Support" plugin which have (or at least had) the logcat view pane at the bottom (near TODO, Version Control and Terminal).

Comment: The best next thing would be https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console, if in fact you see any console

Answer (score 0):

Set
`Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_INFO);`
in your create() class, the log will be shown in the "Run Window".